# XML parsing a header with attributes in it?

Tags: javascript, xml

Im working with XML-code in Javascript to try and create a heatmap, the XML looks like this:

```
<trk>
 <name>Oscar</name>
 <trkseg>
 <trkpt lat="20.922436" lon="-32.950274">
      <ele>35.23</ele>
      <time>2013-04-28T09:23:11Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="21.231232" lon="-30.9123123">
      <ele>35.23</ele>
      <time>2013-04-28T09:23:11Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  </trkseg>
</trk>
```

But I cant seem to be able to target the "trkpt" as it contains the lat= and lon= value, which is always different. How can I target that header? I have tried using the:

```
getElementsByTagName("trkpt")
```

but it cannnot find the information - What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

A code snippet which explains what I have tried so far:

```
var xmlParsing = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xmlDoc = "Hello";
var readyString = "asd";

xmlParsing.open("GET","3.xml", false);
xmlParsing.send();

xmlDoc = xmlParsing.responseXML;


var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("trk");
var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("trkseg");  

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){ 



  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

  document.write(": <em>");

  for ( e=0; e < y.length; e++) {
  document.write(y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }

  document.write("</em> <br>");
  }
```

This is mostly just to try and print the values to see what I am doing.

The result returns this:

`Oscar`    `nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull`

Comment: Attributes will have no effect on `getElementsByTagName`. Whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by the code you've shared. Try creating a reduced test case. http://sscce.org/

Comment: So, how can I target them then?

Comment: SHow us yout complete code please, the issue has to be elsewhere.

Comment: What does `getElementsByTagName("trkpt")` return?  Does that find the element?  Do you know how to get the attributes from the element?

Comment: BTW: you do realize that your document isn't valid XML, as it lacks the XML declaration? (shouldn't be the issue here, but still)

Comment: @Paul — Your question seems to be "How do I select trkpt elements even if they have attributes?", did you intend to ask "How do I select trkpt only if they have specific attributes with specific values?"

Comment: @JohannesH. — The XML declaration is optional unless you aren't using XML 1.0 or UTF-8.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - it returns a null value - If you guys give me a minute I can update it with a snippet of code and show you.

Comment: @Quentin  it is? hm, didn't know. I'll look it up (I always want to read the specs), thanks for the information!

Comment: @Quentin , Very feasible - Ill update with a small code example and get back to you, but yes - I want to target the trkpt - even when it contains special values.

Comment: @Paul: The attributes have no bearing on `getElementsByTagName` whatsoever.

Comment: @JohannesH. I know Johannes, I tried to minimize the XLM so you guys wouldnt have to stare at unecessary code :). I guess Ill include everything next time.

Comment: @RocketHazmat How come I cannot encase the result then? I am really lost here.

Comment: Does your actual XML have multiple `trk`, `trkpt` or multiple anything else in it? If so, please reflect that in your sample.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes - There are several trkpt, Ive updated the XML to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you. And what value are you trying to output in this line: `document.write(y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);`

Comment: @RocketHazmat , I thought I had to target the parent in order to retrieve the child? Incorrect?

Comment: @Paul: incorrect, `getElementsByTagName` travereses the tree and looks for children and grandchildren and so on. It just doesn't go upwards.

Comment: @Paul:  I mis-read the code.  Never mind.  You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

The `childNodes` of this element are not what you expect.  If you do:

```
console.log(y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].childNodes);
```

then you'll see the following:

```
[text, ele, text, time, text]
```

You need to filter out the text nodes.  You can try using:

```
y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].firstElementChild.textContent
```

But if you want the other nodes, then you should loop, and filter out text nodes:

```
var children = y[e].getElementsByTagName("trkpt")[0].childNodes;
for(var c=0; c < children.length; c++){
    if(children[c].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
        // Do whatever
        console.log(children[c].textContent);
    }
}
```